# Bulk delete Django by ids

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I writing a project using Django REST Framework, Django and Postgres as a database. I want to bulk delete in one query. So, it is possible to do without writing a query using pure SQL?
There is an example, but the count of executet query equal length of a list of ids (for example, if in `delete_ids` 2 ids, Django will execute 2 queries):

```
delete_ids = [...]
MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=delete_ids).delete()
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` There is an example, but the count of query equal length of a list of ids:`? Do you mean that `len(delete_ids)` queries are executed? How do you measure it? Remember that you can validate your query using `.query` property.

Comment: What do you mean with "*but the count equal to the length of a list of ids*"?

Comment: @gonczor yes, for example, if in list 2 ids, Django will execute 2 query.

Comment: How do you check it?

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi: no Django will do this in a single query. In fact the `.delete()` function of the objects will *not* be called (given these exist). What can happen however is that if there are foreign keys, it will result in some extra querying to let the foreign key on-delete's "ripple".

Comment: @gonczor Django-silk package.

Comment: I would advice to test this with four example 10 `MyModel`s, and thus check what queries exactly are done. Normally the only source of extra quering are some "triggers" attached to `MyModel`.

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi This does not prove that these additional queries are performed in the query you've written. I'm pretty sure they happen elswhere in the code.

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi can you check what queries are executed by switching on logging to console in django modules at `INFO` level? This will print each executed query.

Comment: @gonczor My fail, I saw the mistake. Django always executes 2 query: for `filter` and then `delete`.

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi: no normally it does not (unless you use a strange database system). It typically generates a query like `DELETE FROM table WHERE condition`. I think perhaps the other query is an *invisible* one originating from the API framework.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried to hardcode ids and I saw that Django executes 2 query in one line `Answers.objects.filter(id__in=[50,51]).delete()`. I use Postgres as database.

Comment: This should not happen. Django should be able to build a single query to delete objects you want using those 2 functions. The biggest advantage of django's ORM is exactly that it can do such things and execute queries only when they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using the `filter` and `delete` together using raw sql query.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/

```
 MyModel.objects.raw('DELETE FROM my_model WHERE id IN (%s)', [','.join([list_of_ids])])
```

For fast deletes won't advice but you can also use

```
 sql.DeleteQuery(MyModel).delete_qs(qs, using=qs.db)
```

Answer (score 0):

jackotyne's answer is incorrect as a `DELETE` statement cannot be run with django raw. The idea behind django raw is that it returns a queryset, but `DELETE` won't do that.

Please read the reply to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958914/django-orm-raw-delete-query-not-deleting-records).
You will need a database cursor as stated in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(
        'DELETE FROM "appname_modelname" WHERE id IN (%s)' % ', '.join(delete_ids)
    )
```

Of course it is better to filter with django and get a queryset and do a bulk delete with `queryset.delete()`, but that is not always possible depending on the data's logic.