# Django ORM raw delete query not deleting records

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I am using *raw_sql* queries for my convenience for keeping my database minimal I am deleting extra records. By this query

```
#d is from a loop and has values
res=MyModel.objects.raw("DELETE FROM mydb_mymodel WHERE mydb_mymodel.s_type = '%s' and mydb_mymodel.barcode = '%s' and mydb_mymodel.shopcode = '%s' and mydb_mymodel.date = '%s'" ,[d.s_type,d.barcode,d.shopcode,d.date])
```

It is not deleting records in database but

when I do `res.query` and run it from `postgres` console it works!

Yes I can use

```
MyModel.objects.filter(s_type=d.s_type,barcode=d.barcode,
shopcode=d.shopcode,date=d.date).delete()
```

but what I am missing in *raw_sql*?

Comment: What if you remove the quotes here, so `%s` instead of `'%s'`? That being said, one of the real advantages of Django is a builtin ORM that abstracts away your database, and makes more readable queries (and does all the mapping, serialization, etc. itself).

Comment: I tried and query with quotes works otherwise I get errors! So quotes are fine here as they are part of postgres query syntax and that is of type string to I compare like `mydb_mymodel.s_type = 'sale'` instead of `mydb_mymodel.s_type = sale `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [**`.raw(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) is *not* executed eagerly, it is, just like most Django ORM queries performed lazily. It thus returns a `RawQuerySet` object with the query in the object. For example:

```
>>> User.objects.raw('BLA BLA BLA', [])
<RawQuerySet: BLA BLA BLA>
```

A query like `BLA BLA BLA` does not make any sense: a database will error on it, but still we retrieve a `RawQuerySet`.

You can force evaluation by for example iterating over it, and then we get:

```
>>> list(User.objects.raw('BLA BLA BLA', []))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/djangotest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BLA BLA BLA' at line 1")
```

So the `list(..)` forces evaluation, and now the database of course produces an error. However even if it was a valid *`DELETE`* query, it would still raise an error, since such query does not return any record.

In order to make `DELETE` calls, the Django manual specifies that you should [use a cursor [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(
        "DELETE FROM mydb_mymodel WHERE s_type = '%s' AND barcode = '%s' AND shopcode = '%s' AND date = '%s'" ,
        [d.s_type,d.barcode,d.shopcode,d.date]
    )
```

But I think it is probably a lot simpler to specify it like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    s_type=d.s_type,
    barcode=d.barcode,
    shopcode=d.shopcode,
    date=d.date
).delete()
```

This will construct a `DELETE` query, and serialize the parameters properly. A `.delete()` query is done eagerly, so the odds of making above discussed mistakes is a lot lower: if the ORM is implemented correctly, then we do not need to worry about that.

Comment: Yes! you are right querysets are *lazy* and you were right about *quotes* too because it gets formatted as ''sale'' that throws error at running.. I checked and it works thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.db import connection
def executeQuery(self, sql, params=[]):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            sql,
            params
        )
```

use it like:

```
executeQuery("DELETE FROM mydb_mymodel WHERE mydb_mymodel.s_type = '%s' and mydb_mymodel.barcode = '%s' and mydb_mymodel.shopcode = '%s' and mydb_mymodel.date = '%s'" ,[d.s_type,d.barcode,d.shopcode,d.date])
```